# Spring.net and Oracle Coherence integration

Tags: integration, spring.net, spring-integration, oracle-coherence

I probably suck as Googling stuff, but I couldn't find any link that mentioned whether its possible to integrate Spring.net with Oracle's coherance product.

Does anyone know if Spring.net has wrapper libraries for the same ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [spring integration project for .net](http://www.springsource.org/extensions/se-springintegration-net) is still listed as a [spring.net extension project](http://springframework.net/modules.html), it's status is ["incubator"](http://www.springsource.org/extensions/lifecycle) and it hasn't had any commits [since March 2010](https://fisheye.springsource.org/graph/se-springintegration-net).

From the [project homepage](http://www.springsource.org/extensions/se-springintegration-net):

> The Spring Integration for .NET project will use the design and code
>   base of the Spring Integration project as a basis, adapting the code
>   as need to support .NET idioms and move in the direction to take
>   advantage of .NET only features such as Lambda expressions and
>   extension methods.

I'd suggest you first find out if Spring Integration for Java supports Oracle's Coherance and if so, you *might* have a slight chance to get this working in .NET too.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Coherence provides a native .NET client that you can use to access it from any .NET application, including Spring.NET-based apps.

Here is a link to docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/index.htm

What you are interested in is covered in the **Client Guide** (Parts I and IV) and **.NET API Reference**.

My book, [Oracle Coherence 3.5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847196128), also has two chapters on .NET and [POF (Portable Object Format)](http://coherence.seovic.com/coherence_blog/2009/09/why-portable-objects.html), as well as a full blown WPF sample application talking to a Coherence Java backend.